# Formatting bullet lists in Trello

Tags: trello, formatting

The cards description field in Trello says they are supposed to accept markdown. However, I can't seem to be able to use stars to format a bullet list.

All my text is put on a single line, with alternate italics. That's understandable, but still, not the behavior I expected.

Is there a way to format bullet lists in Trello?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate this behavior. Are you sure you are including a blank line at the top of the bullet list?  If not, you'll get something like this:

List 1
 * foo
 * bar
 * baz

List 2

- foo
- bar
- baz

Answer (score 1):

Try the below example, just you have to add a blank newline between the name of the list and the items.

```
Ingredients:

- Eggs
- Oil
- *Optional:* milk
```

Output:

Ingredients:

- Eggs
- Oil
- *Optional:* milk

Answer (score 0):

Trello use Markdown. According to that  It should be written as follows:

```
Previous line(+empty line)

- First item
- Second item
- Third item
```

OutPut

---

Previous line

- First item
- Second item
- Third item

---

you can read more [here](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet)